# IntelliJ can't index remote maven repo

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

I am trying to index Maven Repositories in IntelliJ so I can search for classes, but I get an error every time. I am using the latest version of IntelliJ. Why am I unable to update them?

[image]

[image]

This is what appears in the logs

> 2021-07-08 09:43:48,949 [70347579]   WARN -      #org.jetbrains.idea.maven - Failed to update Maven indices for: [central] https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2
> org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.CannotStartServerException: Cannot connect to the Maven process. Try again later. If the problem persists, check the Maven Importing JDK settings and restart IntelliJ IDEA
> at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.RemoteObjectWrapper.perform(RemoteObjectWrapper.java:84)
> at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.MavenIndexerWrapper.createIndex(MavenIndexerWrapper.java:61)
> at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.indices.MavenIndex.createContext(MavenIndex.java:382)
> at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.indices.MavenIndex.updateOrRepair(MavenIndex.java:335)
> at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.indices.MavenIndices.updateOrRepair(MavenIndices.java:128)
> at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.indices.MavenIndicesManager.doUpdateIndices(MavenIndicesManager.java:324)
> at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.indices.MavenIndicesManager$3.run(MavenIndicesManager.java:288)
> at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$TaskRunnable.run(CoreProgressManager.java:998)
> at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcessWithProgressAsync$5(CoreProgressManager.java:497)
> at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressRunner.lambda$submit$3(ProgressRunner.java:228)
> at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcess$2(CoreProgressManager.java:178)
> at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:688)
> at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:634)
> at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:64)
> at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:165)
> at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressRunner.lambda$submit$4(ProgressRunner.java:228)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1700)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:668)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:665)
> at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1.run(Executors.java:665)
> at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
> Caused by: java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 127.0.0.1; nested exception is:
> java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
> at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:623)
> at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(TCPChannel.java:209)
> at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(TCPChannel.java:196)
> at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:132)
> at java.rmi/java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invokeRemoteMethod(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:217)
> at java.rmi/java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:162)
> at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy169.createIndexer(Unknown Source)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
> at com.intellij.execution.rmi.RemoteUtil.invokeRemote(RemoteUtil.java:150)
> at com.intellij.execution.rmi.RemoteUtil.access$400(RemoteUtil.java:21)
> at com.intellij.execution.rmi.RemoteUtil$1.lambda$invoke$0(RemoteUtil.java:134)
> at com.intellij.openapi.util.ClassLoaderUtil.computeWithClassLoader(ClassLoaderUtil.java:31)
> at com.intellij.execution.rmi.RemoteUtil.executeWithClassLoader(RemoteUtil.java:202)
> at com.intellij.execution.rmi.RemoteUtil$1.invoke(RemoteUtil.java:134)
> at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy169.createIndexer(Unknown Source)
> at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.MavenServerConnector.createIndexer(MavenServerConnector.java:61)
> at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.MavenServerManager$6.create(MavenServerManager.java:474)
> at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.MavenServerManager$6.create(MavenServerManager.java:461)
> at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.RemoteObjectWrapper.getOrCreateWrappee(RemoteObjectWrapper.java:43)
> at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.MavenIndexerWrapper.getRemoteId(MavenIndexerWrapper.java:154)
> at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.MavenIndexerWrapper.lambda$createIndex$0(MavenIndexerWrapper.java:61)
> at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.RemoteObjectWrapper.perform(RemoteObjectWrapper.java:78)
> ... 23 more
> Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
> at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
> at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:399)
> at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:242)
> at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:224)
> at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
> at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:609)
> at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:558)
> at java.base/java.net.Socket.(Socket.java:454)
> at java.base/java.net.Socket.(Socket.java:231)
> at com.intellij.execution.rmi.RemoteServer$1.createSocket(RemoteServer.java:174)
> at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:617)
> ... 47 more

Here is a screenshot of my Maven config:

[image: Maven config Screenshot]

Comment: Please check idea.log ("Help | Show Log in...") for errors.

Comment: There are no errors related to this. I blew away the entire log then tried updating the dependencies, but there are no related events.

Comment: No info in logs about connection to repository?

Comment: @y.bedrov I found a log error message and added it to my original post.

Comment: Do you use any antivirus software that might block maven processes?

Comment: @y.bedrov I use no AV software on my Mac.

Comment: Please attach screenshot from "Preferences | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Maven | Importing".

Comment: @y.bedrov Done, it's added at the bottom.

Comment: Please try to use different "JDK for importing".

Comment: I've tried Java 8 and 11 and OpenJDK 8 and 11. None of them work.

Comment: Please try to backup/clean folders used to store settings/configs (https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519-Directories-used-by-the-IDE-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs) and run IDE with defaults.